# Disable public folders via Group Policy

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-7, libraries

I would like to disable all "Public Folders" from users' Windows 7 libraries using a group policy. How would I go about implementing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Libraries physically exist as XML files located in %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries.  You could simply attach a login script to a group policy that replaces those files with a version you like.

See this Microsoft document for some details about [Library Definition File Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd861346.aspx#id0370055).

Comment: Is there a Group Policy that sets this?  It would be more "simply" modified that way, but I appreciate the input!

Comment: I have searched for policies or scripts to work with libraries in the past.  I am not aware of any existing policies that do anything with the libraries.  For the most part group policies only work directly with settings in the registry.  If you need to change configuration files on the file-system you have to write your own script or find one from someone else.